# How many number between 1 and 1000 satisfy a certain condition?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, divisor-counting-function, least-common-multiple

How many positive integers less than $1,000$ are multiples of $5$ and are equal to $3$ times an even integer?

It is simply asking for multiples of $5$ and $6$

Is there a way to do this without guessing or counting? This is from the SAT.

I have tried it, but I counted all, and found common ones, the answer was $33$.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a multiple of two numbers it is a multiple of the least common mutliple, in this case the least common multiple of $6$ and $5$ is $30$. You now want to find how many multiples of $30$ are under $1000$

Hint: $33(30)=990,34(30)=1020$

Answer (score 2):

For a number to be a multiple of $x$ and $y$ it must be a multiple of the LCM of $x$ and $y$.  So in this case, how many integers less than 1000 are multiples of 30?  The 33rd multiple of 30 is 990, the 34th is 1020, so 33 it is.

Comment: Beat me by < 1 minute!

Comment: It's an easy question, so being first to answer is a matter of luck more than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a number is a multiple of both $m$ and $n$ if and only if it is a multiple of $\text{lcm}(m,n)$. In this case, this is $30$. So the question sis how many positive itnegers are less than $1000$ and divisible by $30$. The answer is $ \left\lfloor \frac {1000}{30} \right\rfloor = 33 $. Can you see why?

Answer (score 0):

Don't get yourself confused, "multiples of 5 and 6" could mean something else, as in, for example, "multiples of 5 and multiples of 6;" that would be quite something else entirely. Let's look at the exact wording of the question, which is the following, right?

> How many positive integers less than 1,000 are multiples of 5 and are equal to 3 times an even integer?

So, multiples of 5 include: 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, ..., 990, 995, 1000. But there's another condition and we need to remove some of these multiples of 5. We need multiples of 5 *that are also* thrice an even integer. So we need multiples of 10: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, ..., 990, 1000. But they also need to be multiples of 3, so what we're really looking for are multiples of 30: 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, ..., 990.

Without guessing or counting? You can compute $\frac{1000}{30}$ and round down to an integer, in this case, 33 (notice that $34 \times 30 = 1020 > 1000$).

Now, me, I like to do these things *with* guessing *and* counting. Notice that $30^2 = 900$. After 900, there are another three multiples of 30 before we go over 1000, so that's another way to get 33.